# Access to the Absolute Screen Scale Value

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, gestures

I'm looking for the `absolute screen scale` value.

For example, when you bind to the `gestureend` event, you can access to `event.scale` data which is an around of `1`:

1. `case: scale > 1` **Zoom In**
2. `case: scale < 1` **Zoom Out**

This data instead of being absolute, is relative to the state before the event was triggered.

For example:

- the user zooms to a level (let's say) `2`
- then the user zooms out to a level (let's say) `1.8`. 
  Finally, the result will be that **the viewport is still zoomed**, but the `scale value` will be `< 1`.

So, my question is, how can I access to the `absolute zoom scale` value? In other words, how can I compare the `scale value` over the `initial scale value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in this way:

```js
function getCurrentScale() {
  return document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;  
}

const INITIAL_SCALE = getCurrentScale();
let lastScale = INITIAL_SCALE;

document.addEventListener('gestureend', () => {
  let currentScale = getCurrentScale();

  console.log("scale", {
    initial: INITIAL_SCALE,
    last: lastScale,
    current: currentScale
  });

  lastScale = currentScale;
});
```